# What is the fundamental difference between jQuery $.ajax & dojo.xhrPost?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo, difference

I tried implementing these two methods on two buttons as shown below. 
Button 1

```js
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "xhrServer.xsp",
     data: "some=name=random=data",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "html"
   }).done(function() {
     alert("success");
   })
   .fail(function() {
     alert("Something went wrong. Please try again or contact system administrator.");
   })
```

Button 2

```js
var xhrArgs = {
  url: "xhrServer.xsp",
  content: "some=name=random=data",
  handleAs: "text",
  load: function(data) {
    alert("Data posted.");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error occurred while posting data.");
  }
}
dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

On the firebug console, for dojo.xhrPost request, there is an additional entity with the name "Parameters" is shown.
What is that?
This is affecting the way the data is read on the server side.

Comment: I think the difference is in the way you are sending post data. In jquery you have explicitly provided the type of content (`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`) you are sending. Whereas in dojo.xhrPost you have not specified any content type. So in dojo the content type will be URL encoded. If you want to specify the content type in dojo you need to set the headers property ( i.e `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}`) in the `xhrArgs` object. The **handleAs** property in `dojo.xhrPost` is for handling the response and does not relate to how the data needs to be send.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var xhrArgs = {
  url: "xhrServer.xsp",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  postData: "some=name=random=data",
  handleAs: "text",
  load: function(data) {
    alert("Data posted.");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error occurred while posting data.");
  }
}
dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

By default, in dojo the content type will be URL encoded & sent as parameter. If we want to specify the content type in dojo we need to set the headers property ( i.e headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}) in the xhrArgs object.
This sends the complete data in raw form to the server, just like jQuery $.ajax.
Thank you for the help  @frank.